# Barcode scanning in salesforce

Tags: apex

I have a reuirement like i need to scan the barcode with i-pad and the related barcode comes in the input field in apex and then i will do further modifications based on this.ANY IDEAS?

Comment: Can you please let me know the barcode scanner app name?

Comment: try this http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/03/reading-barcodes-in-salesforce1.html

Comment: That broken link was just missing an 'l' at the end (.htm instead of .html). [Here's the correct link](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/03/reading-barcodes-in-salesforce1.html).  Skimming through the link, it uses web workers, which have [pretty wide support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers), but you should probably confirm that it will work with all of your target devices.

Comment: @ruslan i am not using any app.@tushar I followed the bob buzzard blog to achieve the functionality.